# Why am I getting JINativeWrapper.g.cs file not found error when running my Xamarin app?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When I try to run my Xamarin app on my M1 MacBook, it builds and works fine. But when I run this function:

```
async void loginHandler()
    {
        var loginText = login.Text;
        var passwordText = password.Text;
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var json = new StringContent(
            JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { username = loginText, password = passwordText })
        );
        var result = await client.PostAsync("https://localhost:443/api/account/login", json);
        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var TokenJson = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            //await DisplayAlert("alert", "message", "cancel");
        }
    }
```

It crashes and shows this error:[image: error image]

How can I fix it? I'm using visual studio 2022.

Comment: have you stepped through the code to determine which line is causing the crash?  Have you tried adding an exception handling?  Have you tried using the IP/FQDN of your server instead of localhost?

Comment: var result = await client.PostAsync("https://localhost:443/api/account/login", json);
This line gives me the error. The server works fine for other people doing the task.

Comment: use the IP/FQDN of your server, not localhost.

Comment: you mean like this? var result = await client.PostAsync("https://127.0.0.1:443/api/account/login", json);

Comment: that is the loopback address, not the server IP.  It is no different than using localhost.  "localhost" is telling the device/emulator to **connect to itself**, not the server running the services.

Comment: it's still giving me the same error, i think it has something to do with visual studio not my server or the way i connect to it

Comment: For clarity, show exactly the code you used, that is "still giving the same error". So people don't have to read through all these comments, I recommend editing the question itself to show what you are now trying (which should be the IP/FQDN of your server, according to Jason's comment).

Comment: Try creating a new simulator. I was getting this on a Google Pixel 5 after updating VS4M 2022 17.0 then I created a new Nexus 5 with updated IDE that resolved it for me. However, it still does not work on the pixel.

Comment: I am also getting the same problem with debugging Android apps on my OnePlus N10 on Visual Studio 2022, seems there is a problem with VS that is causing it to fail when catching all kinds of Android exceptions. Would love to hear of any possible solutions.

Comment: I too am getting this issue.  Both on VS 2022 for Mac and Windows.  Also, the same issue on ALL Android simulators and real devices.  Any updates on this issue?

Comment: I also have the problem a newly created project in VS for Mac

Comment: Downgrading forms to `5.0.0.1874` one year back did not help

Answer (score 0):

Try using an iOS emulator. Seems like Visual Studio needs to fix this problem with android emulators.

Answer (score 0):

For me, my VS2022 instance was pointing to version 8 of the JDK.  My Android app is targeting Android 12 (SDK 31).  Once I updated my JDK to 17 (or 11+) I was no longer getting the error.  Not sure if that will help anyone or not, but that is what worked for me.

Comment: Hi - how did you update and change the JDK? Was this on Mac?

Comment: On VS2022 for windows, it's Tools->Options->Xamarin->Android Settings->Java Development Kit Location.  Just set that to path of the newer JDK.